# How to configure database for existing app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have downloaded one app from github which of course doesn't have `database.yml` file so I can't run server and play with it.

App use these gems:

```
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.11'
gem 'paranoia', '~> 1.0'
```

What should I do?

If you need any other file or whole gemfile, I will update my question.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Configure the `config/database.yml` with the following content, and adjust the parameters according to your local mysql setup:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: blog_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-mysql-database

Comment: Thank you Prakash.. Can you tell me what should I put in that database field? 'Blog_development' is for app from rails guide. Name of my app?

Comment: That is the name of your existing database in mysql. In general, I would suggest you go through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html / https://www.railstutorial.org/book to get a better understanding of the rails framework.

Answer (score 1):

create a database.yml file in config folder and paste the below code:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: existing_database_name
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

username and password is your mysql username and password